# Ftrace "function" enabling fails with resource busy

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, embedded-linux, ftrace

I am trying to enable "function" tracer in ftrace after going through

- https://lwn.net/Articles/290277/
- https://lwn.net/Articles/548894/
- https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux_for_real_time/7/html/tuning_guide/using_the_ftrace_utility_for_tracing_latencies

Here are the commands.

```
# cat /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/current_tracer                             
nop
# cat /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/tracing_on
#cat /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/tracing_on
1
# echo function > current_tracer                             
-sh: echo: write error: Device or resource busy
#
```

Is there something I missed because of which I am getting "Device or resource busy" when I try function tracer in ftrace.

Any help will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I had this too. In my case I had the `rasdaemon` process reading some trace files preventing the `current_tracer` from being switched.
Here is how I figured it out and solved it.

First I ran lsof:

```
$ sudo lsof 2>/dev/null | grep /sys/kernel/debug/tracing
bash      2990940                            root  cwd       DIR               0,11         0          1 /sys/kernel/debug/tracing
rasdaemon 2997322                            root    5r      REG               0,11         0     132936 /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/instances/rasdaemon/per_cpu/cpu0/trace_pipe_raw
...
```

My bash was the first one, but the other processes were from the rasedaemon service. I stopped it with:

```
systemctl stop rasdaemon.service
```

Then it worked:

```
$ echo function | sudo tee current_tracer
function
$
```

Answer (score 0):

Fwiw my issue was that I had a reader on the `trace` or rather `trace_pipe` file in my case. The reader in my case was `bpftool prog tracelog`.

Comment: And what is a solution for that issue? Without the solution this is merely a comment, not an answer.